# How to enqueue my scripts and style for the best page speed score

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to optimize site speed by I seem to get the following message:
"Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

Source:
[https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=wwwallaboutcats.com][1]

I looked through the functions.php file and It seems to be something to do with:
Enqueue scripts and styles for front-end.

```html
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles for front-end.
 *
 * @since Ribosome 1.0
 */
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ribosome_scripts_styles' );
function ribosome_scripts_styles() {
 global $wp_styles;

 /*
  * Adds JavaScript to pages with the comment form to support
  * sites with threaded comments (when in use).
  */
 if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
  wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

 // Adds JavaScript for handling the navigation menu hide-and-show behavior.
 wp_enqueue_script( 'ribosome-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20140711', true );

 $font_url = ribosome_get_font_url();
 if ( ! empty( $font_url ) )
  wp_enqueue_style( 'ribosome-fonts', esc_url_raw( $font_url ), array(), null );

 // Loads our main stylesheet.
 wp_enqueue_style( 'ribosome-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), '', RIBOSOME_VERSION );
 
 // Custom style
 wp_enqueue_style('ribosome-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri()."/custom-style.css");

 // Loads the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
 wp_enqueue_style( 'ribosome-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'ribosome-style' ), '20121010' );
 $wp_styles->add_data( 'ribosome-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
 
 // Dashicons
 wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
 
 // Font Awesome
 wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
 
 // Toggle search
 wp_enqueue_script('ribosome-toggle-search', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/ribosome-toggle-search.js', array('jquery'), RIBOSOME_VERSION, true);
 
}
```

Comment: It means that you have styles and scripts in the head or before the fold (visual part of the browser screen). That said, you should move all your scripts to end of the page html and use async flag where possible for the JS.

Comment: Could you show an example of how it should look like?

Comment: Here is a video showing how to approach to this very common issue : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj9LnsgdiWA
And here ia a page describing the problem and solution for the javascript https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking.html